# Find out the number of a symbol to access it

Tags: symbols

In http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/symbols/ I read that `\boxright` from txfonts or pxfonts can by used together with other fonts by doing the following:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxright}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{128}
```

There is another symbol in txfonts and pxfonts that I'd like to use. How can I get its number so that I can use a similar `\DeclareMathSymbol` to access it? The symbol I'm after in txfonts and pxfonts is `\Diamondright`:

[image: \Diamondright]

Comment: For future reference here's what I used to get the symbols I was after: `\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{pxsyc}{m}{n}% Use 'pxsyc' for Palatino and 'txsyc' for Times and Computer Modern
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxright}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{128}% Lewis's 'would' counterfactual
\DeclareMathSymbol{\diamondright}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{132}% Lewis's 'might' counterfactual`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the [`fonttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fonttable) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{txsyc}
\end{document}
```

There you can see it's 132.

[image: font table]

Comment: this not working with xelatex and ttf font

Comment: @Witold No, it doesn't; the package is thought for eight bit fonts.