# Sharp or angled v in math mode (\varv)

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I'm trying to achive a more angled $v$ that is more distinct from $u$. The default math mode v looks like this in the default font:

[image: Math mode 'v' in default font]

What I'm trying to achive is something like this (from `txfonts`):

[image: math mode 'v' in txfonts]

(Edit: the picture is a bit misleading - I posted it to demonstrate the angledness. I'm not trying to get the Greek letter "nu", but rather the classic Latin letter "v" which is straight-lined and mostly symmetric.)

I remember I used to be able to get the alternative v by using `\varv` (analogously to \varphi), but I guess this was just a command defined in the template I used when I didn't know much LaTeX. I can't find a package that defines `\varv`. Ironically (and confusingly), the angled v is default in `txfonts`, and to get the rounded one, there is a package option called `varv`.

I'm using the default fonts right now (Computer Modern / `lmodern`), but I might switch to Minion or Palatino plus matching math (`mathpazo` for Palatino, forgot what the math font for Minion was called), so an ideal solution would be somewhat font independent.

Comment: The latter "v" is often achievable with `$\nu$` (if you are not planning on using nu).  It can be font-dependent, however.

Comment: You could also just [import a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764), if needed.

Comment: The `newtxmath` package provides a `v` in math mode that looks more like a `\nu` than a `u`. (It also provides a `varg` option that changes the appearance of the `v` back.) It uses—as the name suggests—a Times-like font for math-mode. There is also `newtxtext`.

Comment: the shape of that "v" from times (which can't be distinguished from "nu") is the exact reason that, for setting math in times, in metal, the rounded "v" and "w" were substituted from (i believe) century schoolbook.  if you think this "v" and the "u" from the same font are indistinguishable, you're only scratching the surface.

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to get a "nu" shape (which is straight on the left side and curved on the right, a bit like a harp), but rather a symmetric, angled "v" (like in Times New Roman). Sorry if the image was misleading.

Comment: Use \mathcal{V}. No need for any packages.

Answer (score 13):

Grab `\varv` from [`txfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts) using guidelines from [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}% txfonts
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varv}{\mathord}{matha}{118}
\begin{document}
$v\ \varv\ u\ \nu$
\end{document}
```

How do you know `\varv` is character 118? Use [`fonttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fonttable)'s `\fonttable{txmi}` (see [Find out the number of a symbol to access it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32769/5764)):

[image]

Comment: Very informative, but how do you know the rest of the info for `txfonts`?  For example, `matha` & `txmi`?  And what does `OML` mean?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I viewed [`txfonts.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/txfonts/input/txfonts.sty) to find `\varv` and worked my way back from there to see which font the element comes from. Using the package's `letters` alphabet overwrites the existing selection, so I used `matha` (which hadn't been defined/used before). For the other stuff, see section **3.5 Declaring symbol fonts** (p 14) of the [LaTeX2e font selection guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/fntguide.pdf).