# Import 'u' and 'v' from txfonts

Tags: math-mode, symbols, extract, txfonts

Unfortunately, I am not so good at extracting single characters from the other fonts, so I would like to ask for some help.

I need to import 'u' and 'v', that are used in math mode, from  `txfonts`

[image]

I am aware of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130569), but the solution there corrupts other math characters for me. I guess that is because there is no `\DeclareFontFamily` and `\DeclareFontShape` to exclude there.

[image]

Here is the code I am using

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{polynom}

\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE10
    <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
    <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lwavy}{\mathopen}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rwavy}{\mathclose}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}


% --- Get fancy 'u' and 'v' --- %
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varru}{\mathord}{matha}{117}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrv}{\mathord}{matha}{118}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\lambda^3-\lambda^2-5\lambda-3 = 0,\\
(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-2\lambda-3) = 0,\\
(\lambda+1)(\lambda+1)(\lambda-3) = (\lambda+1)^2(\lambda-3) = 0,\\
\lambda_{1\,[2]}=-1, \qquad \lambda_{2\,[1]} = 3
\\
\\
f(u) = u^2+3u
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

And also I would like to use them nativly, so that I don't need a command for them like `\varu`, `\varv`,
simply use it straight forward `f(u) = u^2 + 3u`

Comment: Please, add a sample document which we can play with: what math font are you using?

Comment: @egreg Sure, I've added it.

Comment: What would be the meaning of using two letters from Times in a context where Computer Modern is used?

Comment: I'd like to add my objection to mixing fonts unnecessarily. Aside from the aesthetic, it can cause problems when switching to a journal's class file (if you plan to submit for publication), causing extra work for the production team..

Comment: You don't seem to be aware that, in traditional math journals set in metal using a Times font, the "v" was substituted by the more round "v" from Century Schoolbook because the Times "v" was too easily confused with the Greek "nu".  This is the style copied in Computer Modern.  If you are using the "sharp" Times "v". promise that you will never use "nu" in the same document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get very strange symbols because you're redeclaring the symbol font `matha`, a name which is used by `mathabx`.

You can change the shape of “u” and ”v” by

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathtx}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{117}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{118}
```

(note the change in the font family name), but the result will be *very* disputable.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{polynom}

\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE10
    <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
    <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
    <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
    <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
    <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
    <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
    <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{mnlargesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lwavy}{\mathopen}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rwavy}{\mathclose}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}{mnlargesymbols}{'136}


% --- Get fancy 'u' and 'v' --- %
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathtx}{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{117}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{mathtx}{118}

\begin{document}

\[
r+u+v+w=\mathrm{horrible}
\]

\begin{gather*}
\lambda^3-\lambda^2-5\lambda-3 = 0,\\
(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-2\lambda-3) = 0,\\
(\lambda+1)(\lambda+1)(\lambda-3) = (\lambda+1)^2(\lambda-3) = 0,\\
\lambda_{1\,[2]}=-1, \qquad \lambda_{2\,[1]} = 3
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I do really need `mathabx` in my project. Is it possible to leave it and make 'u' and 'v' from `txfonts` work?

Comment: @antshar Did I remove `mathabx`, perhaps? *You* were not using it for some symbols, because of the redefinition of `matha`, which I fixed.

Comment: Ohh... I am so sorry. I copied your code, but ran mine.

Comment: Just perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @egreg -- If you are changing the "v", the "w" should also be changed to be visually compatible.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My idea was precisely to discourage the OP in pursuing this strategy.