# How to look up "font table"

Tags: font-encodings

I'm trying to look up "addresses" of specific "characters" in a "font table" for a font in Latex. I've come accross these "font tables" in the past, but I can't currently locate them. I think there exists commonly used terminology for the quoted terms, but I don't know what it is, so I'm not even sure what keywords to use in an internet search for such a "font table".

To help explain what I'm trying to describe by the quoted terms, here's a snippet of Latex code that I picked up from some source along the way:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\let\sum\relax
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{cmlargesymbols}{"50}
```

A "font table" would tell me that the `\sum` character is `"50` for computer modern.

To summarize my questions:

1. What is the correct terminology for my quoted terms?
2. Where can I find these "font tables"? (I'll be able to find it using an internet search, probably, given the correct terminology.)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Find out the number of a symbol to access it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32769/5764), [Is there a simple way to print out all the available characters in a LaTeX font set?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210142/5764), [How do I know what symbols/characters are available in a font package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131058/5764)

Comment: If any one of them answer your question, please close it as a duplicate of the appropriate one.

Comment: Output encodings: `texdoc fontenc` e.g. `texmext.enc` etc. The `.etx` files provided with `fontinst` are informative.

Comment: "addresses" is properly called "slots".  "Character" renditions are properly called "glyphs."  The "font table" is properly called, voila, the "font table" (see the `fonttable` package and the `\fonttable` macro that comes with it).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131058/how-do-i-know-what-symbols-characters-are-available-in-a-font-package